# ng-bind-html on single property in object using $sce

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Scratching my head here trying to understand the `$sce` service in Angular 1.2

I have an array of objects I'm pulling from a REST API. I'm taking the returned objects and appending some customer rating information to the object. I added a `rating` key that stores the average score out of 5. I've also added a `rateDisplay` key that constructs a visual representation of the average score.

Object is like so:

```
{ 
    name: "Awesome, Inc.",
    id: "23423121",
    ...
    rating: "5/5",
    rateDisplay: "<span class='icon-circle'></span><span class='icon-circle'></span><span class='icon-circle'></span><span class='icon-circle'></span><span class='icon-circle'></span>"
}
```

Obviously, when I have my HTML like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="business in businesses">
    <td>{{ business.name }} <br/> {{ business.rateDisplay }}</td> 
</tr>
```

The string representation of `rateDisplay` is only showed, rather than the desired HTML output.

If I modify my JS to include the `$sce.trustAsHtml` method, I'm able to see the HTML output of `rateDisplay`, but the rest of my data no longer displays and I still get the error of `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.`

The HTML at that point looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="business in businesses" ng-bind-html="business.rateDisplay">
    <td>{{ business.name }} <br/> {{ business.rateDisplay }}</td>
</t>
```

Here's part of my service in a little bit more detail (took out a large, irrelevant part, let me know if you want to see the whole thing):

```
listRatings: function(names, businesses) {
    // avgFinal and fullRating constructed before this
    for (var business in businesses) {
        if (businesses[business].id === names[name]) {
            businesses[business].rating = avgFinal;
            businesses[business].rateDisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml(fullRating);    // y u no work!
        }
    }
};
```

Which I then call in a controller, passing in business ids stored in a `names` array and `$scope.businesses` for the `businesses` argument.

What should I do to sanitize my `rateDisplay` while still preserving other data stored in the same array of objects? Are there other sanitization methods I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

`businesses` is an object as far as I noticed. So you shall write `ng-repeat` differently;

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in businesses" ng-bind-html="value.rateDisplay"></t>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. Using my `<tr ng-repeat="business in businesses"></tr>` Works fine for displaying data, the issue is stemming from `rateDisplay` not being output as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I went a different route and included `ngSanitize` as a dependency so I'm able to strictly use `ng-bind-html` without using the `$sce` service.